# require or required after as

Tags: past-tense

After 'as', what form of word should come? A noun, an adjective, an adverb or simple past form of verb?

> as **require**

or

> as **required**

Answer (score 1):

> As **required**

is correct as it is simple past tense.

> I do as you **require**

is also correct as **did** and **require** are both in the present tense, alternatively:

> I did as you **required**

is also correct in the past tense.

Answer (score -1):

You need the past participle form of the verb.

> The army will deliver food as **required**.

There are two ways of thinking about the tense/voice of *require* in this structure.

First, you can think of *required* being in passive voice.

> The army will deliver food as *(food is)* **required**.

We don't explicitly say "food is" in this case, but it is implicitly there and that's why require takes the past participle form.

Secondly, you can think of "required" as an adjective form of a verb. This would be similar to the following:

> The window is **broken**. (**Broken** is an adjective describing the state of the window.)
>
> You need to attach all **required** documents. (**Required** describes the attribute of the documents.)

In either case, the answer is: **required** is correct.